# Power Automate - Loop through already filtered Excel

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, power-platform

I`m trying to build a power automate solution, so I have a already filtered Excel file and I have to loop through each row and check for something. The problem is, when I use the connector "List rows present in a table" it start from very first row in the Excel ignoring the filter. Is there any possibilites to fix that? I know about "Filter query" build in the connector, but the filter in excel has always different values.

Thanks in advice

I use the connector "List rows present in a table" it start from very first row in the Excel ignoring the filter.

Comment: What do you mean by filtered Excel file? Could you please explain it?

Comment: So my Excel table is already filtered (by built-in filter in excel). I have over 1000 rows, but I need only like 20 of them. The power automate ignores the alredy built-in filter :(

Comment: Have you considered using the MS Graph's Excel endpoints? I think about this one in particular: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-usedrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http ? It's more powerful and more interesting than the out-of-the-box Power Automate connectors.

Comment: PowerAutomate standard Excel actions couldn’t give two hoots about a filter on a table that you’ve applied through the gui. The data still exists in the table and the filter on the front end can actually be applied by user when using the web version of Excel. Maybe look at using Office Scripts as it can work with row visibility.